# Prevent onclick code in submit button from executing if onblur returned false

Tags: javascript

The text field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nm" name="marks" value="60" onblur="return(myFunction())"/>
```

the button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="val();" />
```

The following is my function in onblur code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nm");

    if(x.value>12) {
         alert("error");
         x.value="0";
         x.focus();

         return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

E.g., if the user changes value of the `nm` text field and clicks on the next text field then the alert must be shown (if returned false), but in case the user changes value of the the `nm` field and then clicks on the SUBMIT button, then the function code in the `onclick` in submit button must not run if `onblur` returned `false`. At present, the function in `onclick` gets executed if `onblur` returned `false`.

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A:**

save onBlur function return into a variable and acces it on the beginning of val() function to know if you have to execute the rest of the code or not.

**Option B:**

Modify button element interactively on onBlur.

Button with id="button"

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="submit" onclick="val();" />
```

new onBlur function:

```
function myFunction()

      {
         var x = document.getElementById("nm");
         var button = document.getElementById("button");
           if(x.value>12)
             {
               button.removeAttribute("onclick");
               alert("error");
               x.value="0";
               x.focus();
               return false;
             }
             button.setAttribute("onclick", "val();");
             return true;  
       }
```

Have in mind both options will require a valid onBlur() after and invalid one for onClick to work again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. It saved a lot of my time. I was figuring a way out for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I think onclcik function is enough to know value is greater than 12 or not

```js
function val() {

    var x = document.getElementById("nm");

    if(x.value>12) {
         alert("error");
         x.value="0";
         x.focus();

         return false;
    }
    
    //do whatever you want 
    
    return true;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nm" name="marks" value="60" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="val();" />
```